# Fatal Error - Could not open xlsx for reading PHPspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I'm having trouble loading an excel spreadsheet using PHPspreadsheet. I receive the following error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Could not open "GradeTrackingv2.xlsx" for reading. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/excelTest/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php:151 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/excelTest/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php(133): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::assertFile('GradeTrackingv2...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/excelTest/grades.php(33): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile('GradeTrackingv2...') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/excelTest/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php on line 151

This is the code in my PHP file....

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
$inputFileName = "GradeTrackingv2.xlsx";
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputFileName);
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$data_array =  $spreadsheet->toArray();
```

I think it has something to do with my original file being copied from OneDrive. My original excel file lives in OneDrive and this is where I use it. I want to be able to copy this to my server periodically so its contents can be viewed by students. I'm working in xampp at the moment and if I copy the file from OneDrive to the htdocs folder I get the above error. If I create a spreadsheet in the htdocs folder and copy the contents of the excel into the new xlsx file it can be read. This isn't ideal, as it is quite time consuming, I'd just like to copy the file for convenience. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I had some too trouble using excel files from one drive.Are you sure anyone had the file open? Did you try to open and Save as copy the file?

Comment: Saving a copy direct to the xampp folder worked. Saving a copy to the documents folder on Mac and copying it to xampp worked. But saving a copy to one drive and copying over resulted in the same issue. An extra step, but one I can live with thanks. Although will have to see if I get similar errors when I move it to the live web server.

Comment: @KenLee the file is copied from a OneDrive folder to xampp. Would this still be the same with logged in credentials?

Comment: I think one drive applied some strange rules to the files, cause I olso had this work around saving a copy of the file